# How to get google map search results in android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-search-api

We will get driving directions from google maps by framing an URL and getting KML file. This is a service provided by google. Like this many available, but i don't know all those :-)

Now i want google map search results like above. What is the URL and output file format to get the search results.

If anybody know these things please reply me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are interested in the Google Places API

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

You make requests and then parse the resulting XML/JSON

Comment: what i want exactly is after opening maps.google.com in search bar if we enter words like america it will show some results. I want to get those results. I think it is different from Google places. Am i correct ??

Comment: You can use Google places to do what you want. Form a request URL as that page describes, and pass in the search as the `keyword`, along with the `location` and `radius`, and then display the results to the user